# how to write list to file without [] in python

Tags: python, list

I write a list like `[1,2,45,6]` to a file.

```
next_queue += _follower_ids
nextqueue_file = open("data_queue.txt","w")
nextqueue_file.write(str(next_queue))
nextqueue_file.close
```

This records the queue in my program, if my program fails I can read the progress in the file, but the problem is the list in file shows up as:

```
[1,2,45,6]
```

with `[]` in the file it makes this process hard. How do I write it just as `1,2,45,6` with no `[]`.

Comment: You forgot the parentheses at `nextqueue_file.close`.  It means you are *not calling* the method.  The file will not be closed by the command.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
nextqueue_file.write(", ".join(map(str, next_queue)))
```

Comment: You can remove the space after the comma since the OP did not use spaces in his example.

Comment: @jamylak: Well, he didn't include spaces in his rendering of `str(next_queue)` either, even though they're present there. The question is specifically about losing the `[]`, which is what I've done.

Answer (score 2):

```
nextqueue_file.write(','.join(map(str, next_queue)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
with open('data_queue.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write(','.join(str(x) for x in next_queue))
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is already written for you, no need to reinvent the wheel:

```
import csv

with open("data_queue.txt", 'w') as f:
   csv.writer(f).writerow(next_queue)
```